# Matrix invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-equations

If A is a matrix such that $A^2 - A - I=0$ then show that $(A + cI)$  is always invertible when $c\ne2$  and $c \ne1 $. I have no idea where to begin with this

Comment: Hint: Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A^2 = aA + bI$, it is easy to see that the inverse is given by $$A^{-1} = \frac{A-aI}{b}$$ (You can verify this by computing $A\frac{A-aI}{b}$).

But we want to find an inverse for $A+cI.$ To do this, we want to write an equation of the form $$(A+cI)^2=\lambda_1(A+cI)+\lambda_2I$$ so that we can use the above result.
By using the identity $A^2=A+I$ given in the question, we can directly write
$(A+cI)^2$ in the desired form. I think you can do the rest :)